# Tracking movie titles using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision, movies

I'm trying to find a way to crop/obtain offsets of Movie titles via Google Cloud Vision API.

Here's an example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyJqF.jpg

I've tried to use FACE_DETECTION, LOGO_DETECTON, and event LABEL_DETECTION but I can't seem to get a result for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Face detection is obviously for faces, Logo detection is for logos, Label detection is to identify objects... To extract text from an image, you will need OCR.

[OCR (text detection)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) is what you actually need.